# Ways to make a background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am trying to **put a background image in a content div and make only the image blur** but failed so far. I managed to get the background-image to show up when the code for the image is in the content div itself (code below). In other words without making an additional div for the image. But in this case the whole content obviously becomes blur if, for example, I put filter: blur(...);

The second method was to make a background-image div. But I managed either to push the content right under the image or put the image somewhere behind the content so It's not visible.

How would you propose to do a background-image and fix my issue? My codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hGBjA

CSS

```
h2 {
font-family: Open Sans;
color: #0099F1;
padding-left: 20px;
text-align: left;

}

#bizpartners ul {
list-style-image: url ("http://www.peopletraining.co.uk/people_training_april_2012002002.jpg");
}


.right {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 100%;
min-height: 400px;
max-height: auto;   
z-index: 5;
margin-bottom: 5px;
background: rgba (255, 255, 255, 0.3);
border: 1px solid #000000;  
background-image: url("http://www.worldswallpapers.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Nature-Wallpapers-2014-2.jpg");
background-size: cover;
filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.right p {
margin-left: 30px;
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This is showing up on codepen  with a blurred background-image as intended, so... Whats the problem exactly?

Comment: @somethinghere The content itself became blur. The intention was to make only the background-image blur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it really quick, i hope it's ok!

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/81yawoxg/

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="text">CONTENT HERE</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
position: relative;
width: 1280px;
height: 700px;
}

.background{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
z-index: 100;
background-image: url("http://www.worldswallpapers.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Nature-Wallpapers-2014-2.jpg");
filter: blur(5px);
-webkit-filter: blur(5px);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.text{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
z-index: 200;
padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I see, you made 3 separate contents. It does work in pen. I'll try to import that to my main code. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah i made 3 different contents and work with z-index and place them with top and left

Comment: WooHoo! It works! Magic of programming. :) Really saved me a lot of time...not to say that there's plenty of work to do anyway, though.